# Why do all the questions appear on the left with tons of useless whitespace?

Tags: support, mobile-web, homepage, question-lists

Is this an update to the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) web-site? Meta still looks the same.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a mobile mode. Are you on a mobile device?

Comment: Why ping Tim Post of all people? (And no, that's not actually gonna work...)

Comment: I didn't have anything to do with that, but I'm ready to take full responsibility for anything else you feel could go better with blame properly assigned. Speaking of 'that', what in particular are you talking about?

Comment: @TimPost I thought you only take responsibility for ['drive by' downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/165773)

Comment: I click on the 'mobile site' button but nothing happened even after a refresh. It finally changed on me, and I had no idea what happened to the site. When you posted your answer I remembered what I did. Sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: full site]

Scroll down to the bottom of the page and click that link. You're looking a the mobile version of the site - presumably you clicked the "mobile" link in the footer at some point...

Comment: I remember, I click on the 'mobile site' button but nothing happened even after a refresh. It finally changed on me, and I had no idea what happened to the site. When you posted your answer I remembered what I did.

Comment: Clearly *something* happened...

Comment: @CalebKleveter You may have been on a page which doesn't support the mobile view when you clicked it, and it switched when you finally changed to a page which was mobile-friendly.

Comment: Working for Microsoft as well now @Shog9?